# Why only the [☓] button is grayed out, but [☐] and [—] are not?

Tags: c, winapi, button

Here's my C code:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include<windows.h>
HWND ConsoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
HMENU SystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(ConsoleWindow, FALSE);
DeleteMenu(SystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DeleteMenu(SystemMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
DeleteMenu(SystemMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
```

I want to grey out [☓], [☐] and [—] button, but only the [☓] button is grayed out.

Why? Thanks.

PS: Though [☐] and [—] button are not grayed out, they are disabled.

Comment: Try EnableMenuItem with `MF_DISABLED | MF_GRAYED` flags.

Comment: @Alex Farber Oh, I try, so bad, get worse! [☐] and [—] button is neither grayed out nor disabled. But THX for your reply.

Comment: Another option is try to remove `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` and `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` styles using `SetWindowLongPtr` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding the buttons works:

```
LONG_PTR style = GetWindowLongPtr(ConsoleWindow, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
SetWindowLongPtr(ConsoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, style);
SetWindowPos(ConsoleWindow, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_DRAWFRAME);
```

SetWindowPos() isn't strictly necessary, at least on Windows 8.1, I included it just in case.  The buttons are visible to the user for a brief moment, no simple fix that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks! But can you change the code into C? I am a beginner in programming.

Comment: This is C code.  Maybe you have to move the *style* variable declaration to the top of the function, a C89 restriction.